# How to get type definition for Stripe imported directly by <script> tag

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, stripe-payments

The recommended way to use the Stripe library in frontend code is through a `<script>` tag:

```
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

This creates a global `Stripe` object.

How do I get this object appropriately typed, and the objects it creates? This is a Vue3/Typescript project.

Comment: From [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including)... _"We also provide an npm package that makes it easier to load and use Stripe.js as a module. For more information, check out the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js)."_

Comment: That does not really answer the question. I'm following the recommended procedure.

Comment: It's in their docs, how is that not recommended? In fact, it even says... _"Asynchronous loading of JavaScript is **generally recommended** [...] The easiest way to asynchronously load Stripe.js is to use the npm module as described above. It does asynchronous loading by default."_

Comment: At the very top of that page it says: 

"Include the Stripe.js script on each page of your site—it should always be loaded directly from https://js.stripe.com, rather than included in a bundle or hosted yourself."

Comment: That's referring specifically to the `https://js.stripe.com/v3/` script. They're just saying not to download it locally

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? Or are they saying that you should do both?

Comment: That one is built specifically for use directly in a `<script>` tag. I suppose they want you to use their CDN link so it's always up-to-date. The Node.js module is not the same and is pinned to a specific version which you can manage using something like Dependabot

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the way:

`npm install --save-dev @stripe/stripe-js`

Then in the .vue file:

```js
import type { Stripe as StripeType, StripeElements } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
...

declare var Stripe: StripeType;
```

Comment: Nice. This will work well with the `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">` method of inclusion

Comment: Yeah, it's probably unnecessary. Their docs are very confusing, but it basically seems that the NPM bundle just fetches the main library anyway, *and* creates a script tag. So might as well just use the NPM module.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe provides both UMD packages for use in `<script>` tags as well as an [ESM module](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) for use in bundled projects.

```sh
npm install @stripe/stripe-js
```

This provides [TypeScript declarations](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js?tab=readme-ov-file#typescript-support) for your project which will be picked up by your IDE for code completion, type-safety, etc.

```ts
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = await loadStripe('<your API key>'); // typed as Stripe
```

Also, as recommended in the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including), this is the best way to load Stripe

> "Asynchronous loading of JavaScript is **generally recommended** [...] The easiest way to asynchronously load Stripe.js is to use the npm module as described above. It does asynchronous loading by default."